# So I've got two problems with my armature

Tags: rigging, armature

Please, keep in mind that I'm quite new to this whole world of rigging.

The first problem is that I've got a bone that is moving my model in a way that it shouldn't. No it's not a weight problem, Please take a look.

Here's one of bones that is working properly

[image]

As you can see, it bends model properly (or maybe not, I'll improve weights soon)

[image]

However, this little guy right here, whenever I move him.

[image]

The whole model moves along, and I seriously have no idea why?

[image]

And second issue is related to face. I also have no idea on why is this happening?

[image]

When I turn my model's face around, eyes and teeth just sort of pop out for some reason.

[image]

I've tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> but it didn't help much.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post and make your question title specific to the issue you are having.

Comment: @RayMairlot: Thanks for correcting me, I will add in future posts

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy fix of all your problems, try **Rigify**. It will give you complete custom controls and you may assign bones to mesh **With automatic weight**.

Enable **Add on**

[image]

Add **Armature**

[image]

Adjust bones according to your character, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply **Location**, **Rotation and scale**.

Hit **Generate** button under Rig tab in right side bar.

Select mesh, select custom shapes (in this order) Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select **With automatic weight**.

I hope it will make your life easy, Good luck :)